# Will gc root root be cleaned up if referenced by a child object?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

Debugging memory issues and I noticed that a gc root was referenced by a grandchild node. I know that the gc can generally handle grap hg s that are active, but does it handle it correctly if the root is part of the cycle? Or is this a leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, GC can handle active graphs, even if the root is part of a cycle. The GC can trace the references from the root to the grandchild node, and then back to the root, which eventually breaks the cycle. This allows the GC to collect the memory used by the objects in the cycle.

Nowadays, most garbage collectors are designed to detect and collect cyclic references, also called garbage cycles or memory leaks. However, the effectiveness of garbage collection in handling cycles depends on the specific GC algorithm and its implementation.

Some garbage collectors, such as the mark-and-sweep algorithm with reachability analysis, can manage cyclic references by identifying objects that are no longer reachable from any GC root and reclaiming their memory. To mark and sweep objects, these algorithms use graph traversal techniques, breaking cycles and freeing memory occupied by unreachable objects.

If you are concerned about a potential memory leak caused by cyclic references,, Use memory profiling tools, like Android Profiler in Android Studio, to identify any strong reference cycles causing a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation..One problem I am having with Android studio is that the aar is obfuscated. Working on getting a deobfuscsted build, but do you know a way to feed a proguaed map to Android studio profiling tools? That would make this so much easier.

Comment: As far as I know, Android Studio's built-in profiling tools do not have a direct way to consume a proguard mapping file for deobfuscation, AS profiler work only with unobfuscated code. but there is other tools that can, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031744/best-way-to-profile-proguard-optimized-build-in-android-studio

Comment: There is a fundamental logical error in the question and in turn, in the first section of this answer. Objects referenced by a GC root are *reachable* and hence, will not get garbage collected and should not get garbage collected. It doesn’t matter whether the garbage collector can handle cycles or not, reachable objects referencing each other are not a problem at all.